# Is 一條魚上面月亮 a valid translation of “(a/one) fish above the moon”?

Tags: translation, traditional-characters

I’m a (very) beginner Chinese learner trying to compose some basic sentences; I’m relatively sure I have the right classifier of 條 for 魚, but (among other things) I’m particularly unsure if using 一 is necessary or idiomatic.

Would 一條魚上面月亮 make sense to a Chinese speaker as “a fish over/above the moon”?

Comment: As a very beginner, I think you got the though processes right, but as  @user2249675 pointed out, the word order was wrong, plus the missing 的 word. In Chinese the 的 word is indispensable, and so look at as many sentences with this word as possible and engrave it into your brain, because unless you master this word, you will always have problems. If you are still up to it, try, "a cow that jumps over the moon"? I am sure  someone would be here to help? A hint, it follows the "SVO", (subject, verb, object) word order, where the subject comes first, the verb second, and the object third.

Answer (score 1):

No.

1. The word order is incorrect. You need 一条月亮上面的鱼.
2. "月亮上面" usually means "on the moon", that is, on the moon surface. To express "above the moon, as seen from Earth", you need 一条月亮**上方**的鱼. If instead you mean "above the moon surface", then I would write 一条浮在月面上方的鱼. (浮 = floating)

Answer (score 0):

Fish in space!

There is a fish in orbit around the moon.
有条鱼漂浮在月球轨道上.

Answer (score 0):

over/above = 在...的上方

over/above the moon = 在月亮的上方

a fish over/above the moon = 一尾/條魚在月亮的上方

Answer (score 0):

The individual words you chose are fine, such as the nouns and measure words etc.  However the grammar is completely wrong, relative locations (left right above below inside etc etc) are an example of chinese and english being completely different.

An example of a very basic way to say it would be  魚在月亮的上面。Notice I flipped the location to the end, and notice I added the character 在-- in this use it is equivalent to the english phrase "is at".  The 的 is a grammatical term and doesn't really have a definition, but here it is basically helping show that the moon is strongly connected to the location of the "aboveness".

However just because this is grammatically correct, does not mean its the best answer.  Are we talking about one fish or many fishes? Lets add that 一條 back for clarity.  Also the 上面 is ambiguous, are we talking about being above the moon, or on the surface of the moon? this term can mean both and more, lets add a 高空 to show its high in the sky above the moon and not on the surface.  Now you don't have to worry about how the english and chinese "above" don't match up in meaning 100%.

Now we have 一條魚在月亮的高空上面。A fish is high above the moon. This is already good, but for extra fun we could add a 飛行 to the end: 一條魚在月亮的高空上面飛行。Now our singlular fishy friend is taking a leisurely flight through the sky high above the moon! I think this is much closer to the imagery you wanted.

In real life, you don't always need to add all those extra words to be clear.  Maybe we are already talking about a specific fish, or have been talking about flying above the moon for hours-- you could say this sentence much much shorter with some of the info already at play.

There are actually many other ways to word this sentence, both in word choice and word order. Hopefully this helped give you a basic idea, I tried to pick something closest to your original form (but I wanted to redo it to 高空在月亮上面飛行一條魚 so bad haha, just by what feels most natural to me personally.... I'll stick it here as alternate example).

As long as you make sure you are learning chinese grammar and vocab properly and avoid writing english in chinese form, your language ability will grow swiftly.  And of course, welcome !  （＾ν＾）